# Spotlight not showing the right apps' icons

Tags: macos, spotlight

I have a problem with Spotlight :
When I start typing the name of an app, its icon is usually the c file header's.
For example, for the Activity Monitor :

[image]

How can I restore the real icons instead ?

Regards.

PS : I'm using OS X 10.8.4

Answer (score 0):

This maybe not the right answer but you can re-index your spotlight folders or you whole volumes, follow [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409) for instruction. I also recommend you to use [Alfred App](http://www.alfredapp.com/). It's a best spotlight replacement, IMHO.

Comment: I tried this method : it indexed my volume again but my icons are still the objective c's ones. This applies for all the apps I type in Spotlight.

Comment: Is it open with XCode or open your app correctly? Have you try Alfred app?

Comment: It opens correctly. It's just the icons that are not corresponding to the app. I didn't try Alfred as I want to use Spotlight.

Answer (score 0):

You should give some of the suggestions here a try: http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/15/spotlight-wont-work-fix-a-broken-spotlight-menu-with-these-troubleshooting-tips/

I was also seeing Objective-C icons for all my apps after migrating to a new laptop.

I tried rebuilding my Spotlight index, but that didn't seem to do anything. But killing SystemUIServer fixed it for me.

Note: I'm running OSX Mavericks (10.9)